# force a save as dialog box when downloading a PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, download, save

I am building a website and i want my users to be able to download PDF documents by hitting a 'download' button. However when i try this out it automatically downloads the file and saves to into by downloads folder in chrome and just opens the file in IE.

Does anyone know if there is a way to force the 'save as' dialog box to display so users can choose where to save the file?

Thanks

Comment: i think that's a browser setting

Comment: OK, so there is no way I can code this into the page then?

Comment: It is a browser setting, and you don't have control over that. What you could do, but you really have to know what you are doing, and be aware of the consequences, would be fiddling around with the MIME type settings on your server, and serve the PDFs as some non-existent file format.